# requests_toolbelt.exceptions.VersionMismatchError: The toolbelt requires at least Requests 2.10.0 to be installed. Version 2.6.0 was found instead

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to use Requests in my app. I have followed the instructions on issuing HTTP(S) requests as is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/issue-requests).

I am calling request_toolbels in my code like so

```
from flask import Flask
from routes import configure_blueprints
from modules.filters import init_babel
import requests
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine


def create_app():
    """Create the Flask App"""
    v = requests.__version__

    requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configure_blueprints(app)
    init_babel(app)
    return app
```

When I debug the value of v is 2.6.0. but I am certain I have installed requests 2.11.1

I get the following error when I run my unit tests.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.3\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" C:\Code\zion-alpha\Tests\ZionTestSuite.py true
Testing started at 3:04 PM ...
C:\Code\zion-alpha\Tests\ZionTestSuite.py:1: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'Tests' not found while handling absolute import
  import unittest2
C:\Code\zion-alpha\Tests\ZionTestSuite.py:2: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'Tests' not found while handling absolute import
  from Tests.TestCases.handler_tests import AppTest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.3\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 153, in <module>
    modules = [loadSource(a[0])]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.3\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 65, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "C:\Code\zion-alpha\Tests\ZionTestSuite.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Tests.TestCases.handler_tests import AppTest
  File "C:\Code\zion-alpha\Tests\TestCases\handler_tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Tests.TestCases.Base.base_test import TestBase, app
  File "C:\Code\zion-alpha\Tests\TestCases\Base\base_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    app = TestApp(create_app())
  File "C:\Code\zion-alpha\app\__init__.py", line 12, in create_app
    requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
  File "C:\Code\zion-alpha\lib\requests_toolbelt\adapters\appengine.py", line 133, in monkeypatch
    _check_version()
  File "C:\Code\zion-alpha\lib\requests_toolbelt\adapters\appengine.py", line 145, in _check_version
    requests.__version__
requests_toolbelt.exceptions.VersionMismatchError: The toolbelt requires at least Requests 2.10.0 to be installed. Version 2.6.0 was found instead.
```

Comment: Did you make sure to install the appropriate version the exception is telling you to install?

Comment: Yes I have 2.11.1 version of request installed

Comment: But requests.__version__ = 2.6.0. I don't know why this is the case. I am not using virtual env.

Comment: I suspect this is because of PyCharm. You should try running your tests outside of PyCharm to see if it's affecting your PYTHONPATH and hiding the correct version of requests.

Comment: You should also strongly consider using a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because appengine sdk has its own version of requests. You need to install sdk 1.9.49 to get requests 2.10
older version of appengine sdk embark requests 2.6.0

It does not matter which version of requests you installed in the lib directory. Appengine always defaults to its own version of requests.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install requests==2.10.0` will solve this issue